# Cities: Skyline fails to generate correct menu and freezes on exit

Tags: steam

I just installed Cities Skylines on my linux os which includes a R7 260X Radeon graphics card.
[image]

The game fails to launch with an appropriate menu screen as depicted in the screen shot provided. The image of the menu is centered at the top right of my screen, while the menu clickable buttons are still centered in the screen. The game freezes when I attempted to click 'Exit Game.'

```
Running Steam on linuxmint 17 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150218153139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424273499)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150218153139)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0, 11563, 13285, 15953, 19132, 21350, 28283, 31828, 49307, 53615, 62700, 62892, 62894, 62922, 62923, 62924, 62925, 62926, 62927, 62935, 63065, 63473, 63683
roaming config store loaded successfully - 903 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/root/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "steam://rungameid/255710" "
ExecSteamURL: "steam://rungameid/255710"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
System startup time: 4.07 seconds

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:4387): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
Generating new string page texture 67: 32x256, total string texture memory is 344.06 KB
Generating new string page texture 68: 128x256, total string texture memory is 475.14 KB
Generating new string page texture 69: 512x256, total string texture memory is 999.42 KB
Running Steam on linuxmint 17 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/root/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ExecCommandLine: "/home/root/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Game update: AppID 255710 "Cities: Skylines", ProcID 4702, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Found path: /home/root/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities.x64
Mono path[0] = '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Cities_Skylines/Cities_Data/Mono/etc'
displaymanager : xrandr version warning. 1.4
displaymanager : trying .X11-unix
client :0 has 1 screens
displaymanager screen (0): 1360 x 768
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20150218153205)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Game removed: AppID 255710 "Cities: Skylines", ProcID 4706 
[2015-03-20 23:01:42] Startup - updater built Feb 18 2015 15:31:44
[2015-03-20 23:01:42] Verifying installation...
[2015-03-20 23:01:42] Verification complete
[2015-03-20 23:03:27] Shutdown
```

Above are the error messages from the terminal while steam was running. I investigated the error '`ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/root/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.`' I found a discussion of this error on ArchLinux which suggested the following terminal command fix '`find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" \) -print -delete`
' but was unsuccessful.

What must be done to force this game to run correctly on linux? This game is supposed to be linux native.

Disabling Steam overlay did not fix the problem.

I uninstalled the repo steam and installed latest deb steam, that did not work as well.

[image: drivemanager]

Comment: How did you install the drivers for the graphics card?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block I used sudo apt-get update/upgrade.

Comment: So you just updated the packages? You did not install any driver PPAs or anything?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/47511/215526

Comment: @Cammy_the_block I will post my drive manager screenshot.

Comment: I fixed it. Simply goto steam->games->view game library->right click cities:skylines->properties->general tab->set launch options -> copy&paste '-screen-height 1050 -screen-width 1400' . That's it. ;)

Comment: Awesome! If you solved your problem it'd be great if you post an answer as to help other users.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. Simply go to

```
->steam
->games
->view game library
->right click cities:skylines
->properties
->general tab
->set launch options
-> copy&paste '-screen-height 1050 -screen-width 1400' without quotes
```

That's it. ;)

Comment: This fixed some screen options i had. (dual screen)
but now it still hangs/quits almost directly after loading the game. (main menu when sounds begins playing.) anybody a suggestion for that?

Comment: okey found a "solution" https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/linux-freeze-and-crash-after-10-seconds.848888/